# Previous version of a django-reversion controlled object

Tags: python, django, django-reversion

I'm using what the django-reversion documents call the [low-level API](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) in order to access the reversion history in my own code, apart from the admin. To store metadata, I've extended the `Revision` model by setting up my own model including a `OneToOneField(Revision)`. So far, so good.

But given that reference to a `Revision`, how can I access the revision directly *before* it? For example, to generate a list of changes between this revision and the previous one, is there any more efficient method than calling back to `reversion.get_for_object` and searching the list for the version I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Revision object has a `date_created` attribute, so you could write a query to select the single most recent revision for your object prior to the given revision's `date_created`.  I'd basically copy the implementation of the low-level API's `get_for_date` function, with one change -- use `"date_created__lt"` instead of `"__lte"`:

```
def get_previous(object, date):
    """Returns the latest version of an object prior to the given date."""
    versions = reversion.get_for_object(object)
    versions = versions.filter(revision__date_created__lt=date)
    try:
        version = versions[0]
    except IndexError:
        raise Version.DoesNotExist
    else:
        return version
```

Comment: You can now shorten this to just `versions.filter(...).first()` without the try/except blocks as first will either return an object or None, if there is None.

Comment: Default ordering of Version class is "-pk" -- you might want to add an explicit `order_by('-revision__date_created')` in case that changes someday.

Answer (score 0):

Version objects have a revision attribute, which has two methods, 'get_next_by_date_created', and 'get_previous_by_date_created', which you could use to traverse version history either way.

```
version.revision.get_previous_by_date_created()
```

Comment: This gets you the previous `revision`, not necessarilly the one that contains the `version` for the object you are looking for...